# How to get straight lines svg from Potrace

Tags: python, shell, svg, potrace

Given an greyscale image already skeletonized by *skimage.morphology.skeletonize* or the bool  array obtained.

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSZ5r.png)

I'm trying to get an exact replica of image the in svg using Lines or Bézier curve but "open".

So i tryed Potrace:

[Potrace Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odEMf.png)

Autotrace with centerline (good svg format but lost pixels):

```
autotrace -centerline -input-format bmp -output-format svg -output-file demo.bmp.svg demo.bmp
```

[Autotrace centerline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daBK3.png)

Then Autotrace without centerline:

```
autotrace -input-format bmp -output-format svg -output-file demo.bmp.svg demo.bmp
```

[Same like Potrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmXjn.png)

Potrace show all details but use closed path on the svg, i'm looking for like the path obtained with **Autotrace -centerline**, so an open path (straight line) with all details (without loosing pixels).
I played with Autotrace options without success.

Comment: Have you tried to lower the default [`-error-threshold`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/autotrace)? For example `-error-threshold 1` or `-error-threshold 0.5`?

Comment: Potrace doesn't support centerline tracing. So (as Sphinxxx suggested) you'll need to fiddle with the [autotrace options](https://linux.die.net/man/1/autotrace).  Eg. `-corner-threshold` might be another one to try.